# Hibernate Criteria join to table containing foreign key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables:

```
Client (clientId, firstName, lastName, gender)

Event (clientId, eventId)
```

I need to represent a query similar to the following using Criteria:

```
SELECT c.clientId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.gender, MAX(eventId)
FROM Client c JOIN Event e ON c.clientId = e.clientId
GROUP BY c.clientId, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.gender
```

I have tried this:

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Client.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("Event", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("clientId")).add(Projections.max("eventId")));
```

but it throws an exception on the last line with the message:

> HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: eventId of:
>   Client

How can I specify the join between the `Client` table which itself contains no column related to the Event table but the `clientId` column on the `Event` table is a foreign key back into the `Client` table?

As you can see, it's really driven off the `Client` table and that I only need to select the maximum `eventId` from the `Event` table.  Also, as I mentioned, I am trying to make a change to an existing Criteria query which is based on the `Client` class.  It is used to retrieve all the columns for all active clients.  I just need to add one extra column to the query results - the maximum `eventId`.

Answer (score 2):

Use alias

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Event.class, "et").
createAlias("et.Client", "ct").
setProjection(Projections.projectionList().         
add(Projections.groupProperty("et.clientId")).
add(Projections.max("et.eventId")));
```

For more details on criteria, refer [Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection)

Comment: Not completely true. `Client` class possibly doesn't know about `Event` class.

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious. Because `Client` class does not have `eventId` property, and your criteria is defined for `Client` class.

**When trying to use a property of B class inside a Criteria for A, you have to use Aliases.**

All you have to do is to modify your code like this:

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Event.class, "event");
criteria.createAlias("event.client", "client");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("clientId")).add(Projections.max("eventId")));
```

---

**UPDATED** (based on your comment)

As your query needs `Event` class, you have to have a `Criteria` for this class. So you have to something like this:

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Event.class, "event");
criteria.createAlias("event.client", "client");
//The criteria below, is returning clientId
DetachedCriteria eventCr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Event.class, "event");
eventCr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("clientId")).add(Projections.max("eventId")));
//Now using subqueries you can achieve your goal
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("clientId", eventCr));
```

I don't know for sure what you're looking for, but I hope I have given you some good hints. You might want to try `Subqueries.propertyEq` instead if your query must return a single id.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

The problem is that I am modifying an existing Criteria based query which is configured to be based on the Client class and actually selects a number of other Client columns/fields. Now I just need to add that for every Client I retrieve the maximum eventId from the Event table.

Is there a way to do this with the Criteria still being based on the Client class but with the join to the Event table added in?

Comment: Of course you can do it without `JOIN`. I suggest using `subqueries`. I have updated my answer for you to show how to use `subqueries`. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Matin but unfortunately I still don't get it :-(

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.  Basically your example uses two Criteria objects based on Event so I can't see how I can use them to select columns such as firstName from the Client table.  This is an *existing* Criteria query based on Client and I just need to add one more column.  I don't think I can totally rewrite the query to be driven off the Event table instead.  This query lives in a method in the ClientDAO object.  It's all about Client, not Event.  I am amazed that it's so difficult to simply join to the Event table and grab the maximum eventId!

Comment: As there is no explicit relation between `Client` and `Event` classes (or is there?), you better use two `Criteria`s. And instead of `join`, use `subqueries`. You can use subqueries and still get the result of what you were trying to achieve with join. For that, you should find an equivalent SQL code to replace your old one.